# Why COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME is not visible from --env-file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I deploy my stack with command `docker-compose --env-file up --detach`, but specified project name is not assigned. When I set up it as environment variable then it works `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=proj docker-compose --env-file up --detach`

Why `docker-compose` does not see project name?

Answer (score 0):

Because `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` is option to set configuration of `docker-compose`. docker-compose need to know that default option is changed first before `docker-compose` executed.

`docker-compose` read env file for containers.